# Не работает условие WHERE mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, не работает вот такое условие:

```
"SELECT id, name, lastname FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%$data%' OR lastname LIKE '%$data%' AND type='Контакт'"
```

Как быть?

Comment: Расставьте скобки. у OR приоритет меньше, в итоге ваше условие сейчас звучит как `name like X OR (name like Y AND type=Z)`

Comment: @Mike подскажите а как сделать кроме? допустим вывести все кроме id=1,2,3

Comment: `not in(1,2,3)`

Comment: @Mike так не получается SELECT id, name, lastname FROM users WHERE (name LIKE '%$data%' OR lastname LIKE '%$data%') AND type LIKE 'Контакт' OR sotrudnik not in('".$_GET['id']."')

Comment: А что должно получиться ? И что у вас в поле sotrudnik, только не говорите что несколько значений чараз разделитель которые вы туда пытались записать, вы в таком поле ничего не найдете, тем более с in / not in

Comment: @Mike все намного проще, у меня поиск идет через ajax, в котором не могу получить get значения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что значит не работает? Предполагаю, что нужно `"SELECT id, name, lastname FROM users WHERE (name LIKE '%$data%' OR lastname LIKE '%$data%') AND type='Контакт'"`.

Comment: подскажите а как сделать кроме? допустим вывести все кроме id=1,2,3?

Comment: На примере выше приведенного мной запроса `"SELECT id, name, lastname FROM users WHERE (name LIKE '%$data%' OR lastname LIKE '%$data%') AND type='Контакт' AND id NOT IN (1,2,3)"`.